# C# datarow getchildrow returns no rows

Tags: c#, database, datatable, dataset, foreign-keys

In my DB there are three tables
R(id,num)
RT(Rid,Tid)
T(id,hour)
And there is 1 to many relationship between (R and RT) and (T and RT).
I am using a Dataset to access my DB.

Now I am using code below to retrieve data and it returns empty list:

```
foreach (mDataSet.RTRow rtRow in rRow.GetRTRows())
      console.writeln(rtRow.Tid);//never reaches this line
```

Code for inserting value:

```
rTableAdapter.insert(r.id,num);
tTableAdapter.insert(t.id,hour);
rtTableAdapter.insert(r.id,t.id);
```

Does anyone know what is the problem that I get now rows

Comment: If it's not due to the fact that the db data is indeed empty, we'll need to see some more code.

Comment: By putting a breakpoint on foreach statement check the value of rRow.GetRTRows() in Watch window and assure that it isn't empty

Comment: Tell us your select query with which you are fetching record. Hope you are using a dataadpatter to fill your dataset. share it please how you are doing. And your schema of these three tables may be needed as well to understand the problem in full

Comment: Thanks for the replies. (nieve) DB is noot empty. (Mohsen) it returns an empty list. (Sami) yes I am using dataadapter to fill my dataset. and GetRTRow() is a given method, I am not writing any query for that. I shared more code on how I am inserting data into these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious question first: does `mDataSet` contain data in the table `RT`? In your comment you state that the DB is not empty, but is the dataset also not empty?

Second, when I encountered this problem, it eventually had to do something with the relation as definied in the designer. When you double click the line between the two tables `R`and `RT`(the line with a key symbol on one side and and infinity symbol on the other side), you can examine the properties. Just make sure that the correct columns from both tables participate in the foreign key relation.

As an aside: do you really use such short names for your table and variable names or was it just to provide an example?